# complex join operations conversion from oracle to mysql

Tags: mysql, oracle, left-join

```
FROM   tab1               a,
       tab2                l,
       tab3     cp,
       tab4 jic,
       tab5              c
WHERE  a.member_number = l.member_number
AND    l.challenge_phrase = cp.challenge_phrase_id(+)
AND    IFNULL(a.join_ip_address, a.update_ip_address) = jic.join_ip_address(+)
AND    IFNULL(jic.country_code, '-') = c.iso_code(+)
AND    l.login NOT LIKE 'jfaux%'
AND    a.join_date >= SYSDATE - 14;
```

How can this code be converted to mysql format of left outer join ?

Comment: What approach have you tried yet? Please tell us and then except us to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

ORACLE LEFT (or RIGHT) JOINs full syntax is equivalent to MySQL (except there's no `FULL OUTER JOIN` in MySQL):

**ORACLE**:

```
SELECT a.field, b.field
FROM tableA a LEFT JOIN tableB b on (a.id = b.id)
```

also

```
SELECT a.field, b.field
FROM tableA a, tableB b
WHERE a.id = b.id (+)
```

**MySQL**:

```
SELECT a.field, b.field
FROM tableA a LEFT JOIN tableB b on (a.id = b.id)
```

Comment: You don't get it. There're 5 tables in FROM but only join per 2 table in each of the condition. How to solve this problem in MySQL? Can I write this in MySQL: select .... from tA left join tB on f1=f2, tC left join tD on f3=f4 ....?